# PhantomJS or Selenium Standalone killed after first failed tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, protractor

I don't know if this is a Protractor or PhantomJS error.
I'm running this command, getting this log.
It seems like PhanthomJS or Selenium Standalone is dying after the fist fail test.
Do you need more logs/details to check where is the issue?

```
$ grunt accept:standalone --suite=list
Running "env:rde" (env) task

Running "shell:protractor_update" (shell) task
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

Running "protractor_webdriver:start" (protractor_webdriver) task
Starting Selenium server
Started Selenium server: http://127.0.0.1:4444

Running "protractor:test" (protractor) task
Using the selenium server at https://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Session created: loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@255d17d7, count=1, browserName=phantomjs, phantomjs.binary.path=c:\git\clients\special-offers\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe, version=ANY

Preparing new session

.FF

Failures:

  1) Special Offers list page should have a thumbnail, a title, a description and a CTA
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".ss .details p.body-copy")


  2) sssssssssssssss
   Message:
     UnknownError: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'CBA-D013', ip: 'xxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver


Finished in 29.282 seconds
3 tests, 6 assertions, 2 failures

Session deleted: Keeping the Selenium server alive

c:\git\clients\special-offers\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
>>
>> Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.

Running "shell:kill_selenium" (shell) task
Shutting down Selenium server: http://127.0.0.1:4444

Done, without errors.
```

Bye all!

Comment: NoSuchElementError sounds like a webdriver error.  What does the html and test code look like?

Comment: @MikeWeber nop. The first error is OK. The problem is in the second failure